# Display equations using wiris in Div in Moodle

Tags: php, plugins, tinymce, moodle

I am using **wiris plugin for tinyMCE editor in Moodle**. Using the **wiris editor** I type some equations.
But these equations are inserted in database as

```
<p>«math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«msup»«mi»x«/mi»«mn»4«/mn»«/msup»«/math»</p>
```

this format. And while display these in browser it display as same

```
<p>«math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«msup»«mi»x«/mi»«mn»4«/mn»«/msup»«/math»</p>
```

But I have to display as:
[image]

How can I do this?  Please help me..

**EDIT**

My problem is the equation generated using `WIRIS` is displaying in `tinyMCE editor` as desired, but while displaying in `div/span/table` etc it display as

```
<p>«math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«msup»«mi»x«/mi»«mn»4«/mn»«/msup»«/math»</p>
```

Please refer the image for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once enabled, our filter automatically converts safeXML to formula images in Moodle contexts without any additional logic. 
If you try creating a regular native Moodle question including a WIRIS formula and then preview it, using Moodle's default preview, the formula will show as an image.

If you are trying to display the formulas in a custom module you are building from scratch, the scenario is different. 
Are you filtering the content before displaying it? You need to use `format_text()` so that the filter parses the text you are displaying. 
Please check the code of `/<moodle>/blocks/html/block_html.php` and how `format_text()` is used. We also recommend that you check the Moodle filter documentation at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Filters#A_note_about_performance

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you are using WIRIS in Moodle our formula images are stored in your database as what we call safeXML, which is a slight modification of MathML replacing five characters (http://wiris.com/plugins/docs/resources/encoding-attributes).

However, you don't need any additional configuration for formulas to be displayed as images in Moodle. WIRIS filter automatically converts safeXML into formula images.

Please check that you have enabled WIRIS filter as detailed on step 3 at http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/moodle

Comment: in` tinymce editor` the equations from `wiris` are displayed correctly, but in `div or table` the equations are still display as ` safeXML`. I am already enabled the `wiris filter`.